# WinRT WRL ABI collections

Tags: c++, collections, windows-runtime, wrl

I trying work with WRL and stuck with collections.

I need pass to function additional properties:

```
ABI::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::IDeviceInformationStatics::FindAllAsyncAqsFilterAndAdditionalProperties(
  /* [in] */ __RPC__in HSTRING aqsFilter,
  /* [in] */ __RPC__in_opt ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IIterable<HSTRING>* additionalProperties, ...)
```

but IIterable has no methods to fill it, and has no touch with `IVector<T>` (which has methods for filling, but it abstract interface).

Am I need implement my own vector like [there](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2014/11/10/wrl-implementations-of-ivector-and-iasyncoperation.aspx) or there exist a simpler way to work with collections? What kind of collections return ABI functions under these interfaces?

Comment: You will need to implement your own IVector.

Comment: This function returns result in 'ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<T>', I just give it non initialized pointer to this 'IVectorView<T>'. Result is implemented and has working methods like GetAt(N). Can I use same implementation? Also I read that _collections.h_ implements this interfaces with std containers, but all I see there - c++/cx code.

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: hey, I know it's been awhile, but have you solved it? If so, can you please post a code example of how you initialized that `IIterable<HSTRING>` parameter?

Comment: as @Damyan answered you need implement your own vector or use from [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2014/11/10/wrl-implementations-of-ivector-and-iasyncoperation.aspx) I posted in question. Also there a sample code how use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement your own (or reuse the ones from the link you posted).

Note that IIterable does have a single method, "First", that you can implement if you want to do it yourself.  Have a look in windows.foundation.collections.h for more details.